# Calculating AUC for multiple simple logistic regression models using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, apply, proc-r-package

Let me just start off by saying this is my first time posting a question on stack overflow so I hope I explain this well.

I am trying to calculate the c-stat (area under the curve) for multiple logistic regression simple models.

I have the code for how to do it for one simple model. I have one binary response variable (which is a factor with levels 0 and 1) and 100 predictor variables which are all numeric. Here I use just one numeric predictor variable. This code works.

```
simple_model <- glm(target_variable ~ pred1, family = binomial, data = training_data)
pROC::auc(roc(training_data$target_variable, predict(simple_model, type = "response")))
```

Now what I am trying to do is create a separate data frame which has the name of the predictor variable in one column and its c stat in the second column.

This is what I have tried so far without any success:

```
        auc <- sapply(training_data, 2, function (x) {
               temp_data <- cbind(training_data$target_variable, x)
               multiple_simple_models <- glm(target_variable ~ ., family = binomial, data = temp_data)
               proc::auc(roc(temp_data$target_variable, predict(multiple_simple_models, type = "response")))
})
```

But I get an error that says:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN): '2' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Comment: Hi, 
did you mean to use `apply` (instead of `sapply`)?

Comment: I replaced 'sapply' with 'apply' but now I get another error that reads 'Error in model.frame.default(formula = target_variable ~ . , data = temp_data, : 'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or array'

Comment: When you use `sapply()` the second argument should always be the function. I guess, as the poster above has indicated, you may have desired to use `apply()` instead. 
Note: I've just seen your response above. Will take a look

Comment: Then I see two options:

 - `apply` does not accept a `data.frame` , but it does accept a matrix. (as the error message tells us) . So `apply(as.matrix(training_data), 2, function (x) {` has a good chance of working. 

- the other option is to use `sapply` and to convert your data.frame into a list of vectors with `sapply(split(training_data,cols(training_data), function(x) {...`

Comment: I seem to have confused myself. Should multiple_simple_models have the training data for data = or the temp_data

Comment: should it be multiple_simple_models <- glm(target_variable ~ ., family = binomial, data = training_data) or multiple_simple_models <- glm(target_variable ~ ., family = binomial, data = temp_data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is not far off!

The only outstanding issue, as raised in your comments above, is that you are not able to process the code due to a 'matrix / data frame' expectancy issue - this is because `glm()` expects a data frame, or at the very least something which can be coerced to a data frame *and* with the names of the columns retained. As a result, you can't use `cbind()` since it will create an unnamed matrix.

So - assuming you have access to a `target_variable` vector and a data frame with `predictors` in it - my slight amendment to your code would look something like this:

```
results <- sapply(predictors, function (p) {
     temp_data <- data.frame(p, target_variable)
     temp_model <- glm(target_variable ~ ., family = binomial, data = temp_data)
     pROC::auc(roc(target_variable, predict(temp_model, type = "response")))})

results_data <- data.frame(predictor = names(results), auc = results)
```

Note that you need the extra line for `results_data` since `sapply()` on its own returns a named vector (it automatically simplifies its outputs whenever possible)

Comment: Thank you! I am curious how to create a target_variable vector and a data frame with predictors?

Comment: Suppose your target variable is called `y` and it belongs to a data frame `df` then `target_variable <- df$y` extracts column `y` as a vector and then assigns the name `target_variable` to that vector.

The 'predictors' data frame is just a data frame of predictors, less the target variable. So if your data frame has, say, two predictors `p1`, `p2` and the target variable `y` then a 'predictors' data frame would be a data frame with just `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: Important not to get confused with all of this: all you need is (i) a data frame with all the predictors you want to test (`predictors`), and (ii) a vector which contains the target variable results (`target_variable`). Then the above code should work.